# Java Swing Can't Get Value Of Variable

Tags: java, function, swing, button

Im trying to make a game with two diffrent frames. (I know its not effective) Anyways my problem is i can't get the value of my variable that i changed under actionListener function.

```
public void Pick_Char() {
    
    frame2 = new JFrame();
    frame2.setBounds(100, 100, 925, 805);
    frame2.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame2.setResizable(false);
    frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    
    btnNewButton = new JButton("Gözlüklü Şirin");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        
            Main window = null;
            try {
                 
                window = new Main();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            flag1=true;
            window.frame2.setVisible(false);
            frame2.dispose();
            window.frame.setVisible(true);
            
            
            
        }
    });

public Main() throws IOException {
    Pick_Char();
        initialize();
        if(flag1 == true)
             GamePlay();
      
       
}
```

the variable i talk about is flag1. I declared that variable globally. What im trying to do is when i press the button, it will close that frame and open other frame (which is already working) and give me the flag1 value. I don't get any mistakes, but i can't get value of flag1.
GamePlay function doesn't work. Please help me

Comment: From your code, pushing the button *will* update the `flag1` variable. If you're expecting `flag1` to be true inside `Main()`, it won't be true yet because the button hasn't been pushed yet when `Main()` is run.

Comment: @khelwood i tried to use it in GamePlay Function but didn't worked there aswell. What should i do? i also tried to use button.ispressed function. Same, no mistake, but didn't work

Comment: We have no idea what you're trying to do, other than have alternate JFrames appear and disappear with the left-click of a JButton.  You can do the same thing with one JFrame and a CardLayout that holds each player's JPanel.  Create an application model using plain Java getter/setter classes to hold the game state.  One boolean value in the application model would be which player is active (which JFrame is visible).

Comment: Alternate jframes appear and disseaper with the left-click of a JButton yes. But i can't get value of flag1 after i press the button. I wonder why? this is all i ask

Comment: *"Alternate jframes appear and disseaper.."* Tip: Add @GilbertLeBlanc (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Answer (score 1):

## Introduction

I put together an example Swing GUI to show how a multi-player game can be created where each player has their own `JPanel`.  A timer `JPanel` appears in between showing the player `JPanels` so you have time to switch seats.

Here's Player 1's `JPanel`.

[image: Player 1 JPanel]

Here's the timer `JPanel`, counting down.

[image: Timer JPanel]

Here's Player 2's `JPanel`.

[image: Player 2 JPanel]

I didn't just change the `JLabel` text.  You're seeing two player `JPanels` in one `JFrame`.

## Explanation

When I create a Swing GUI, I use the [model / view / controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (MVC) pattern.  This pattern allows me to separate my concerns and focus on one part of the Swing application at a time.

The MVC pattern using Java Swing works like this:

1. The view reads information from the model.
2. The view does not update the model.
3. The controller updates the model and repaints / revalidates the view.

Usually, a Swing application has multiple controller classes, one for each action.  This example has one `ActionListener` since all we're doing is switching player `JPanels`.

### Model

This application has two model classes, `Player` and `GameState`.  For now, the `Player` class holds a player name.  All other game information about a player, like score, goes in this class.

The `GameState` class holds information about the game state.  The `List` of `Player` instances tells us the number of players and the `int` `playerTurn` tells us whose turn it is.

### View

This Swing GUI consists of a single `JFrame`, with a main `JPanel` using a `CardLayout`.  Each player has their own `JPanel`.  The `JButton` at the bottom of the player `JPanel` switches you to the next player.

Each player `JPanel` contains whatever information from the `GameState` class that a player needs to see to play the game.  There can be other `JButtons` on the player `JPanel` that alter the state of the player.  When the player finishes his turn, he clicks on the next turn `JButton` to pass the game to the next player.

### Controller

Right now, the only `ActionListener` is the one that switches player `JPanels`. There's an internal `ActionListener` controlled by a Swing `Timer` that allows players to switch seats. You can adjust the countdown time in the outer `ActionListener` class.  Other `JButtons` would trigger other `ActionListeners`.

## Code

Here's the complete runnable example.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class MultiPlayerGame implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new MultiPlayerGame());
    }
    
    private CardLayout cardLayout;
    
    private GameState gameState;
    
    private JLabel timerLabel;
    
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JPanel timerPanel;
    
    private PlayerPanel[] playerPanels;
    
    public MultiPlayerGame() {
        this.gameState = new GameState();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MultiPlayer Game");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        this.mainPanel = createMainPanel();
        frame.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        cardLayout =  new CardLayout();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(cardLayout);
        
        List<Player> players = gameState.getPlayers();
        playerPanels = new PlayerPanel[players.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++) {
            Player player = players.get(i);
            playerPanels[i] = new PlayerPanel(this, gameState, 
                    player);
            panel.add(playerPanels[i].getPanel(), player.getName());
        }
        
        timerPanel = createTimerPanel();
        panel.add(timerPanel, "timer");
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private JPanel createTimerPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        
        timerLabel = new JLabel(" ");
        timerLabel.setFont(panel.getFont().deriveFont(16f));
        panel.add(timerLabel);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    public void updateTimerPanel(Player player, int seconds) {
        String text = "" + seconds + " seconds before " + 
                player.getName() + " may play";
        timerLabel.setText(text);
    }
    
    public CardLayout getCardLayout() {
        return cardLayout;
    }

    public JPanel getMainPanel() {
        return mainPanel;
    }

    public JPanel getTimerPanel() {
        return timerPanel;
    }

    public class PlayerPanel {
        
        private final MultiPlayerGame frame;
        
        private final GameState model;
        
        private final JPanel panel;

        public PlayerPanel(MultiPlayerGame frame, GameState model, Player player) {
            this.frame = frame;
            this.model = model;
            this.panel = createPlayerPanel(player);
        }
        
        private JPanel createPlayerPanel(Player player) {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
            panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
            
            JLabel label = new JLabel(player.getName());
            label.setFont(panel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 24f));
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            panel.add(label, BorderLayout.BEFORE_FIRST_LINE);
            
            JButton button = new JButton("Next Player's Turn");
            button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener(frame, model));
            panel.add(button, BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);
            
            return panel;
        }

        public JPanel getPanel() {
            return panel;
        }
        
    }
    
    public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        
        private final MultiPlayerGame frame;
        
        private final GameState model;
        
        private Timer timer;

        public ButtonListener(MultiPlayerGame frame, GameState model) {
            this.frame = frame;
            this.model = model;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            int delayPeriod = 30;
            int turn = model.nextPlayerTurn();
            Player player = model.getPlayers().get(turn);
            CardLayout cardLayout = frame.getCardLayout();
            timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                private int delay = delayPeriod;
                
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent innerEvent) {
                    --delay;
                    frame.updateTimerPanel(player, delay);
                    if (delay < 0) {
                        cardLayout.show(frame.getMainPanel(), 
                                player.getName());
                        timer.stop();
                    }
                }
            });
            timer.start();
            frame.updateTimerPanel(player, delayPeriod);
            cardLayout.show(frame.getMainPanel(), "timer");
        }
        
    }
    
    public class GameState {
        
        private int playerTurn;
        
        private final List<Player> players;
        
        public GameState() {
            this.players = new ArrayList<>();
            this.players.add(new Player("Player 1"));
            this.players.add(new Player("Player 2"));
            this.playerTurn = 0;
        }
        
        public int nextPlayerTurn() {
            playerTurn = ++playerTurn % players.size();
            return playerTurn;
        }

        public int getPlayerTurn() {
            return playerTurn;
        }

        public List<Player> getPlayers() {
            return players;
        }
        
    }
    
    public class Player {
        
        private final String name;

        public Player(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        
    }

}
```