# Wait for Swing Timer to finish not working using a while loop

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, while-loop, timer

I want to wait for a Swing timer to finish before executing the sequential code. I have researched online and every question along the same line seems to differ widely with no concrete answer. However, I did see an answer utilizing a while-loop and a boolean value that determines whether the timer is done.

With the code I have set up here, I expect the following:

1. The initialization of the timer starts and a new Thread is created to execute the timer code
2. The while loop is read, and is stuck, for now, because of the timerDone boolean
3. The timer, when finished, changes the value of the boolean
4. The while loop terminates and the code is continued

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Test {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
    
    
    public boolean timerDone = false;
    
    public Test() {
        start();
        System.out.println("Finished");
    }
    
    public void start() {
        new Timer(100, new ActionListener() { 
            int i = 0;
            
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                i++;
                if(i == 5) {
                    timerDone = true;
                    ((Timer)event.getSource()).stop();
                }
                
            }
        }).start();
        while(!timerDone);
    }
}
```

However, even though the timer code executes, the while loop never terminates. So then, I decided to create a new Thread containing the while loop:

```
Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
    while(!timerDone);
});
t.start();
```

With this addition, the println statement "Finished" prints out immediately and the program never terminates. Either 1. how can I fix this current set up? or 2. how can I correctly wait for a Swing Timer to terminate?

Comment: Your while loop blocks the Event Dispatch Thread and prevents the GUI from updating.  If you want to execute something after the Timer is stopped, put the code after the stop Timer statement.  That's how event-driven code works.

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc I see. I know that solution works where code is put after the stop method but it just seemed inconvenient. There is no work around then?

Comment: No, there is no workaround.  There are many times when you want to return from a method quickly to keep the GUI responsive while still running long tasks on a background thread.

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc Ah ok, thanks.

Comment: Here's a [Swing GUI example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66723969/java-swing-cant-get-value-of-variable/66725007#66725007) that uses a Swing Timer.

Comment: @user16320675 Wow that worked, thanks. I looked more into the keyword volatile and it makes sense

Comment: @user16320675 Yes I was dumbing my problem down. Originally, my problem existed in a GUI I had. Thanks for the other info as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a boolean flag (`timerDone = true`)` invoke a method to do the required work:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test {

    private int counter;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->new Test());
    }

    public Test() {
        start();
    }

    public void start() {

        counter = 0;

        new Timer(100, event -> {
            counter++;
             System.out.println("Timer is running "+ counter);
            if(counter == 5) {
                doAfterTimerStopped();
                ((Timer)event.getSource()).stop();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void doAfterTimerStopped(){
        System.out.println("Timer finished");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was planning to do, thanks for the answer